# Why is calling masm from C# so slow?

Tags: c#, masm, slowdown

Here is a 64-bit masm program to multiply two 64-bit numbers and add a 64-bit number to give a 128-bit result (using the standard 64-bit calling conventions):

```
; public static extern ulong MulAdd64(ulong U, ulong V, ref ulong k);
; Return  (U*V + k) % ß  and set  k = (U*V + k) / ß.
;  U in rcx, V in rdx, &k in r8
; Note  0  <=  0*0 + 0  <=  (ß-1)*(ß-1) + (ß-1) = ß*(ß-1)  <  ß^2
MulAdd64  proc  public
        mov     rax,rcx
        mul     rdx
        add     rax,qword ptr [r8]      ; low part of product
        adc     rdx,0
        mov     qword ptr [r8],rdx      ; high part of product
        ret
MulAdd64  endp
```

This is imported into the C# code via:

```
    [DllImport(@"C:\path\MulAdd64.dll")]
    public static extern ulong MulAdd64 (ulong U, ulong V, ref ulong k);
```

Now here is the same function written in C# along with a test program:

```
public static void TestCS_Masm_Speed ()
{
    ulong x = 3141592653589793238, y = 2718281828459045, aux = 1234567890123456789, lo = 0;
    // just in case the first invocation is excessivly slow
    //lo = MulAdd64(x, y, ref aux);
    lo = CS_MulAdd64(x, y, ref aux);
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Restart();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        //lo = MulAdd64(x, y, ref aux);
        lo = CS_MulAdd64(x, y, ref aux);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Ticks = {0}", sw.ElapsedTicks);
    // verify low-order results  hi:lo = x*y + aux;
    if (x*y+aux != lo) Console.WriteLine("Error in low order result");
    else Console.WriteLine("Low order result is OK");
}

[DllImport(@"C:\path\MulAdd64.dll")]
public static extern ulong MulAdd64 (ulong U, ulong V, ref ulong k);

/*
    Multiplication. We need to multiply two unsigned 64-bit integers, obtaining an
    unsigned 128-bit product. Using Algorithm 4.3.1M of Seminumerical Algorithms,
    with ß = 2^32, the following subroutine computes hi:lo = y*z + aux .  Then
    sets aux to hi and return lo.
*/
public static ulong CS_MulAdd64 (ulong y, ulong z, ref ulong aux)
{
    ulong[] u = new ulong[2],  v = new ulong[2],  w = new ulong[4];
    // Unpack the multiplier, multiplicand, and aux  to  u, v, and w 
    u[1] = (ulong)y >> 32;      u[0] = (ulong)y & 0xFFFFFFFF;
    v[1] = (ulong)z >> 32;      v[0] = (ulong)z & 0xFFFFFFFF;
    w[1] = (ulong)aux >> 32;    w[0] = (ulong)aux & 0xFFFFFFFF;
    // Multiply
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        ulong k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            ulong t = u[i] * v[j] + w[i+j] + k;
            w[i+j] = t & 0xFFFFFFFF; k = t >> 32;
        }
        w[j+2] = k;
    }
    // Pack w into the outputs aux and return w
    aux = ((ulong)w[3] << 32) + (ulong)w[2];
    return ((ulong)w[1] << 32) + (ulong)w[0];
}
```

The optimized C# code is significantly longer than the masm code (153 instructions versus 6 instructions) but runs almost twice as fast (941694 ticks vs 1722289 ticks)!  How can this be?  Everything is passed in registers and there is no memory to pin!  Apparently something is happening between the call from C# and the execution in masm, but what? I can't step into that code.

Comment: Length of source code just doesn't correlate well to execution time.  That underlying assumption is what is the problem here.

Comment: `but runs faster`. Post the code how you measure it.

Comment: As far as I know, there is an overhead when crossing managed/native boundaries... Also, maybe the compiler is able to optimize your long code more than you think and thus the actual code might be more optimal that what you have written.

Comment: As usually one does such performance test in a loop, you might get an idea of the managed <--> native transition by timing the loop on either side.

Comment: I agree with @Servy  that source code just doesn't correlate well with execution time.  My point is that the six instruction multiply-add in masm is nowhere near as complex as the C# code necessary to unpack, do 4 multiplies, repack, and do assorted overhead.

Comment: As @Phil1970 mentions there is overhead going from managed to native code, but the overhead that this test encounters implies that only the more time intensive assembly code should be used with C#.  Otherwise the overhead overwhelms the assembly advantage.  Tracing  the disassembled C# code, over 200 instructions were executed; does this mean that 300-400 instructions were overhead in the masm call?  Is there some attribute that can reduce this overhead - say something that indicates that no memory is modified and that nothing needs to be pinned?

Answer (score 0):

By using Google, you can have a better understanding of the overhead associated to managed / native transitions. Here are some articles:

- [Performance Considerations for Interop (C++)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky8kkddw.aspx)
- [Managed to unmanaged overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074054/managed-to-unmanaged-overhead)
- [What exactly happens during a “managed-to-native transition”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201444/what-exactly-happens-during-a-managed-to-native-transition)

In a case like your, the overhead of adjusting calling convention and other required adjustment is probably higher than the call itself.

**Usually, if you do enough such multiplications, you would batch them together to minimize the overhead. And you would do some testing to find the optimal size.** However, if you are really serious about performance, then you would consider everything like cache size, parallel processing...

I believe that C# compiler can relatively well optimize your code so that at CPU level instructions can be properly sequenced so that there is almost no wasted cycles. It might be able to use SIMD or other tricks to optimize the code. And otherwise, you can probably write much more efficient multiplication in C#.

By the way, why would you write your own code when Windows already provide a function to do such multiplication: [UnsignedMultiply128 function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh802933(v=vs.85).aspx)?

And have you compared [BigInteger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx) performance?